# Downloading video with python not playing while loading

Tags: python, multithreading, video

I have been trying to download a video file with python and at the same time playing it with VLC.

I have tried few ways. One of them is to download in a single thread with continuous fetch and append data. This style is slow but video plays. The code is something like below

```
    self.fp = open(dest, "w")
    while not self.stop_down and _continue: with urllib2 request
        try:
            size = 1024 * 8
            data = page.read(size)
            bytld+= size
            self.fp.write(data)
```

This function takes longer to download but I am able to play the video while its loading.
However I have been trying to download in multiple parts at the same time..

With proper threading logics

```
    req= urllib2.Request(self.url)
    req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (self.startPos, self.end)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = response.read()
    if os.path.exists(self.dest) :
        out_fd = open(self.dest, "r+b")
    else :
        out_fd = open(self.dest, "w+b")
    out_fd.seek(self.startPos, 0)
    out_fd.write(content)
    out_fd.close()
```

With my threading I am making sure that each part of the file is being saved on sequentially.
But for some reason I can't play this file at all while downloading.

Is there anything I am not doing right? Is the "Range" should be modified different way?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out for each block of data in thread mode Range has to be +1 BYTE. So if the first block is 1024 next one is from 1023 to whatever.